# Cannot get Release Keyhash for Facebook Connect Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, key

I am trying to retrieve the Release Keyhash for my app . I am giving the correct password and path to the generated keystore file but still is doesn't outputs my keyhash.

Here's a screenshot of the situation .

[image]

As you can see in the above picture , I've given all the info correctly including my password. My password is the one I entered while generating the `keystore file`. It does not output anything and moves to the next line .

Why is it not printing the `keyhash` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.example.id;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    PackageInfo info;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.id", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                        MessageDigest md;
                        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                        et.setText(something);
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + something, 2000).show();
                    }
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
                    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: will this be the release key ?

Comment: sorry , but I got stuck in another problem , will get back to you as soon as I get there again .

Comment: OK... I tried to use this code , but it is not printing any logs ,`note that` I am running the app in release mode.

Comment: here "something" will be ur output buddy... try to set in edittext or in toast...

Answer (score 0):

Try this when session open

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

By this way your code will become machine independent.